# Asp .net Core : How can I use a model inside a Partial View in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

Unable to use Partial View with model.

I have created a new WebApplication named `WebApplication1`

I have created a partial view named `TestPartialView` inside Shared folder.

In the `TestPartialView.cshtml.cs` file I have created a method named `GetMyString()` which returns a string.

And I am using `@Model.GetMyString()` inside the `TestPartialView.cshtml` file.

I have included `<partial name="TestPartialView" />` tag inside the `_Layout` page below the `<partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />`

When I build there are no errors.

But when I run it, it is giving an error :

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'WebApplication1.Pages.Shared.TestPartialViewModel'."

[image: TestPartialView.cshtml]

[image: TestPartialView.cshtml.cs]

[image: _Layout.cshtml]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your partial view is expecting a model of type TestPartialViewModel but you did not specify that when referencing the partial view from your _layout.cshtml, hence the page by default sends the Parent ViewModel to your partial view which causes the error you are having.

**To Fix**

Simply reference your partial view from _layout.cshtml and also pass the expected model like below

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/PartialViews/TestPartialView.cshtml", 
              new TestPartialViewModel())
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have tried to scaffold a New `Razor Page` to use as a new partial view.

A partial view does not have an associated `PageModel` class (`.cshtml.cs`). A partial view is only a view created in Razor markup (`.cshtml`).

Please refer to this example: [Strongly Typed Partials](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages#strongly-typed-partials). It succinctly shows a `Razor Page` passing data as a model to a `partial view` to render.

You can also always find more information on the [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2)